# Tricky regex validation

Tags: regex

I need to validate string with 2 groups which are separated with one space with next rules:

- Each group needs to be at least 2 character long but less or equal to 15
- Both groups together can't be more than 20 chars long (not counting space)
- Groups can only contain letters (that's simple, it's [a-zA-Z])

Following these rules, here are some examples

- Firstname Lastname (Valid)
- Somename T (Invalid, 2nd one is <2)
- Somethingsomettt Here (Invalid, first one is > 15)
- Somethingsome Somethingsome (Invalid, total > 20)

It'd be simple `[a-zA-Z]{2,15} [a-zA-Z]{2,15}` if it wasn't for that 2+2<=total<=20 condition.

Is it even possible to limit it this way? If it is - how?

**UPDATE**
Just for the sake of it, resulting regex was supposed to be `^(?=[a-zA-Z ]{5,21}$)[a-zA-z]{2,15} [a-zA-Z]{2,15}$`, @vks was closest one to it. Nevertheless, thanks @popovitsj and @Avinash Raj too.

Comment: Why not split on the space in the middle, and separately validate both pieces? This would allow you to trivially check the combined length.

Comment: Is there a reason you have to do this with one regular expression?

Comment: Looks like you have an extra `-` in the middle of your first character class (`[a-z-A-Z]`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^(?=.{5,21}$)[a-zA-Z]{2,15} [a-zA-Z]{2,15}$
```

Try this.See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/nA6hN9/30

Answer (score 1):

You could try the below regex which uses negative lookahead,

```
(?!^.{22,})^[a-zA-Z]{2,15} [a-zA-Z]{2,15}$
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/kL1bL8/2)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with lookahead. Something like this:

```
^(?=.{1,20}$)[a-zA-z]{2,14} [a-zA-Z]{2,14}$
```

Comment: Thanks, modified it to `^(?=[a-zA-Z ]{4,21}$)[a-zA-z]{2,15} [a-zA-Z]{2,15}$` which seems to work like I need.

Comment: @Flyer  did you want to match `Somethings Somethings`?

Comment: @Flyer this is incorrect.the minimum should be 5 not 4.

Comment: @Avinash Raj, yeah it should match since both are >=2 <=15, and total is 20 (not counting space)

Comment: @Flyer also the max should be 15 not 14

Comment: @vks, because that was closest one to what I needed at that moment. And yeah, I know. That was my fault though, at the time of posting I said less than 15 and edited to less or equal later.

Comment: Hey my answer is not the cafe! :p

Comment: @Flyer Why you fail to give the preference to the first?

Comment: @vks could you explain this `Each group needs to be at least 2 character long but less or equal to 15` for me?

Comment: Who cares 14 or 15... and yours is incorrect too, it matches also tabs and enters instead of just a space in the middle.

Comment: yep, `\s` matches tabs and new line characters.

Comment: @vks OMG , he later edited his question. **It's not quite right.**

Comment: Today is a bad day for me :(